# Как в nginx сделать проверку авторизации?

Tags: nginx

Требуется в nginx при успешной авторизации отобразить данные / редиректнуть на другой адрес.

Подключал следующим образом:

```
server{
...
auth_basic "Admin Zone";
auth_basic_user_file .../.htpasswd;
...

location / {
     proxy_pass ...
     proxy_pass_request_body off;
     proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
     proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
 }
}
```

Штука не сработала, т.к. сразу без проверки начинает сразу отображать данные. Если убрать отображение, то запрос на авторизацию показывается. Как решить проблему?

Comment: Поместить auth_basic в location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ оказался на поверхности, но была неясность из-за которой потратил достаточно много времени.
Я открыл приватную вкладку и в ней тестировал путём изменения конфигураций и перезапуска сервера. Но, видимо, в браузере оставался сохранённый кеш и новые изменения не подтягивались. В этом плане я не разобрался, объясните, если знаете, как это происходит у nginx. Помогло закрытие/открытие приватного окна.

Код был в шаге от правильности, и после вышесказанного я сделал то, что @andreymal посоветовал в комменте (спасибо). Итого, работающий код для авторизации и последующего отображения результата на текущей странице.

```
server{
...
location / {
     auth_basic "Admin Zone";
     auth_basic_user_file .../.htpasswd;
     proxy_pass http://... # адрес
     proxy_pass_request_body off;
 }
}
```

p.s. будут полезны ссылки из документации:

1) [базовая авторизация в nginx](https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_basic_module.html);

2) [отображение на текущей странице чере proxy_pass](https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass).